# how to write message in console from ruby controller, when method is called with AJAX call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I want to print message in console from Ruby Controller . and I am using AJAX call for calling method(action). I have already tried following ways to print data:

1. Rails.logger.debug("debug::" + person.name)
2. puts "test"
3. logger.info("session info" + session.inspect)
4. logger.debug "test"
5. render :text => @some_object.inspect

   render can not we used as i got error message that it is already used for rendering a file.

Comment: from where you invoke ajax call?

Comment: on cilck of a button

Comment: in controller you write this code?

Comment: @Jass please add your view code from where you are making an ajax call & also you controller code where you have added `logger.debug "test"` - test should be displayed in your server log

Comment: @uzaif I added this code in controller

Comment: @dkp AJAX call which i am making is in JS file and the code for that is $.ajax {
   type: 'POST'
   url: "/abc"
   data: query
   success: (data)->
   dataType: 'json'
}

Comment: ya add some code so we get idea what you want

Comment: `def abc
 logger.debug("test")
 # demo code @demo
 respond_with @demo, serializer: DemoSerializer
end`   this is code that i am trying

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to simply print in the console, you'll need to include your console.log in the ajax call.  If you are trying to debug the js, you would also put the debugger above the line you're debugging in the js file.

```
$.ajax({ 
  method:'POST',
  url: "/abc",
  data: { query },
  debugger
  console.log('hey')
  success: 
    (data)-> dataType: 'json' 
}
```

If you are trying to debug from the controller, add a byebug or pry in your controller and run your test or hit the controller by navigating to that endpoint through the UI.

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def action
    binding.pry
  end
end

GEMFILE
gem 'pry-rails'
or
gem 'bye-bug' (included in rails new)
```

If you are trying to render text from the Rails controller after an ajax call and without a refresh, you could use a flash message using this pattern:

```
flash[:info] = "text"
flash.keep(:info)
render js: "window.location = '#{path}'"
```

Comment: The Bybug gem was likely added to your Gemfile automatically, so double check there.  However, putting a puts statement in your controller will render in your terminal where the server is running if that line hits. If you do not see it showing up in the terminal then the only explanation is that it's blowing up before that line. I would do a puts at the top of the action and work your way down. If it doesn't hit then there is something wrong with your ajax call, at which point I would start debugging the js.  Also, by navigating to that endpoint in the browser, you might get some useful info.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way to debug in Ruby is to use `pry`, [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug), `web_console` kind of gems.

For instance, with `byebug`

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def some_action
    # your code goes here
    byebug
  end
end
```

And then you're able to start debugging from your console.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this ?? As i want to do this with default functionality of Ruby.